# Canon MX300 does not print under 12.04

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I used to print under 11.10 by using SANE for MX360, with no problem. Upgrading to 12.04 the printing process goes to "stop". The job-printer-state-message (under job attributes) says: "the PPD version (5.2.7 Simplified) is not compatible with Gutenprint 5.2.8-pre1."

Comment: Please visit this page and see how could you identify the problem. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersCanon

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, you can fix it by changing your printer driver.

1. go to your printer: http://localhost:631/printers/
2. in the "Administration" droplist, select "Modify Printer"
3. press continue till you can select your driver and search the list for your printer (next to the name of your printer it will probably say something like Gutenprint 5.2.8-pre1)
4. Press modify printer and that's it!